# 3 columns layout with fluid input in the middle one

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a 3 column layout with two floating divs with fixed with, and a middle one with a fluid width.
My problem is that I want the element inside that fluid middle div to fluid too. For example a text input...

Here's a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/JmarcD/y8850t49/

```css
.wrapper {width: 100%}
.first-box {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 97px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.third-box {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 97px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.middle-box {
    height: 97px;
    background-color: red;
}
.middle-box input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="third-box">
    </div>
    <div class="first-box">
    </div>
    <div class="middle-box">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

If I put 100% on the input it jumps all the way outside... I'm kinda stuck here.

Any tips?

Thank You!

Comment: I didn't quite understood the issue but I want to advise you to use a CSS grid for layout like Bootstrap or Foundation have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one mention here is a solution using [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```css
.bottom {
  width: 100%
}
.first-box {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 97px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.third-box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 97px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.middle-box {
  height: 97px;
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: left;
}
.middle-box input {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first-box"></div>
  <div class="middle-box">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="third-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great since it's supported by IE9. Thanks! (wish I could upvote it)

Answer (score 0):

By using a flex display on the wrapper you can achieve the effect you are trying to, like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="first-box">
</div>

<div class="middle-box">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="third-box">
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
}
.first-box {
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 97px;
background-color:blue;
}

.middle-box{
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

.third-box {
float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 97px;
background-color: yellow;
}

.middle-box input {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you should remove the floats as well

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your divs to the natural order, and use flexbox. Make the wrapper `display: flex` and the flexible div `flex: 1`...

```css
.bottom {width: 100%}
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
.first-box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 97px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.third-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 97px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.middle-box {
  flex:1;
    height: 97px;
    background-color: red;
}
.middle-box input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first-box">
    </div>
    <div class="middle-box">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="third-box">
    </div>
</div>
```